# How do I draw a line between two points in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how to develop this kind of activity in react-native ?.
[activity image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vTTb.png)

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vTTb.png" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The react-native SVG library might be useful for this, can refer to it [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#line)

Answer (score 0):

The element is an `SVG basic shape`, used to create a line connecting two points.

```
<Svg height="100" width="100">
  <Line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />
</Svg>
```

For more refer [here](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg#line).